# Search button with relative position in iphone

Tags: iphone, html, css

I have a problem with iphone and searchbox. The button of searchbox is doubled. 
You can look at this here: http://213927.allegros.web.hosting-test.net (no reclame or spam).

I don't understand why it is so and I have no idea how to fix it.

If you have an iphone and you haven't this problem, please, send the screenshot and your version.

If you have an idea why it is so and how to fix it, please, tell me why.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are programmatically setting the image size, here is a link that shows how to scale images to make the work properly http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/10/01/scaling-images-and-creating-thumbnails-from-uiviews/

You could try making the image half the dimensions and then trying to implement it that way and see if it still is scaled to become the wanted size.

Comment: Thanks man! You helped me a lot coz bug was with repeat in css...
I was fighting with it lot of time.